# Funtime errors using a Java Library requires me to have JRE 8, but Library requires JDK 6 using IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

I started a new project that is just a hello world that has the Commons IO v2.4 Apache Library that uses JDK 1.6 but is unable to run after I build the jar. I added it to the Libraries and Modules just fine, and it executes the methods that I took from the libraries fine on Compile time, but I am using JRE 1.7. I took of the methods to prove that it is just the fact that it is interacting with this library. I did nothing else to this new project.

The JDK for the library is 1.6 but is demanding 1.8 JRE. Is there somethign that I'm missing here? I want to let users run my jar with their minimum JRE being 1.6 so I can target more users, but this is throwign an error.

The actual Error that is being thrown is the major.min error of 52.0, which means that it needs to run it at 1.8 JRE to run a simple hello world.

Comment: How are you building the JAR? maven, IDE?

Comment: I am just using the IDE build to Artifacts, so it creates a Jar. I then just take a bat and call java -jar 'filename.jar'

Comment: It sounds as though your IDE is configured to compile to Java 8. IDEs can usually target different language levels. I'd check the project settings in your IDE.

Comment: I have no idea, I didn't do anything besides wait an hour - not even reset, and it seemed to compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually selecting language level for your project.

Right click project > Open Module Settings:
On right side under sources tab, change language level to required JDK.

Then click on Project tab on left and make sure both JDK version and language version are at correct version.